# LINQ Range of items from List<MyObject>

Tags: linq, range

Using Linq, how can I get a list of objects where their ordinal poistion is between 5 and 27.

There is an **unknown** number of MyObject, so somethings nothing could be found.

**"allItems"** is always in order so ordinal position is required.

Like this:

```
List<MyObject>  allItems = GetAllItems();
List<MyObject>  myRange = allItems.LINQSTATEMENTHERE(5 to 27th items);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a combination of Skip() and Take():

```
int from = 5;
int to = 27;
var myRange = allItems.Skip(from - 1).Take(to - from);
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355660/managing-ranges-with-linq-challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Since you require immediate execution (you want to load the results into a list), there's no need to use LINQ here; you can use the instance [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method on `List<T>`:

```
List<MyObject> myRange = allItems.GetRange(from, to - from + 1);
```

Of course, if you want deferred execution, or you want the technique to apply to other types of sequences, go with Justin Niessner's technique. The one benefit that his technique has is that it won't blow up if there are too few elements to represent the range.